# A word for someone who finds all things beautiful?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

I have yet to find an English word, or in any language, which translates to someone who appreciates the beauty in all things.

Comment: Not as an exact answer, however worth mentioning: "...One of the central experiences of love is the **lover's tendency to see all things beautiful and desirable** as reminders of the beloved,..."  from "The Song of Songs: A Continental Commentary" by Othmar Keel.

Comment: @Sophia Aitcadi A "Joe Merrick"? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Merrick

Comment: But surely all things are not beautiful, are they? Consider, for example, the pogroms in Eastern Europe. An aesthete would not find beauty in these tragedies. Rather, an aesthete has a heightened sense of beauty. They might be more aware of the beauty around them.

Answer (score 5):

Consider, **aesthete**.

[***aesthete***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aesthete)

> *noun*
>
> a person who has or professes to have refined sensitivity toward the beauties of art or nature.

Also, **connoisseur**

> *noun*
>
> an expert judge in matters of taste.
>
> He was a **connoisseur** of life, appreciating the trivial, minute and even mundane things that others would normally overlook.

Answer (score 2):

an **aesthetic** personality will appreciate beauty wherever it can be found.

> [**aesthetic**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aesthetic) (adj) -  "characterized by a heightened sensitivity to beauty"  e.g. *the poet and his aesthetic friends*.

But if you are looking for a word describing someone who finds everything beautiful, someone who sees beauty and finds good in everything, you could say they are a [**Pollyanna**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Pollyanna), after the character in the novel by Eleanor H. Porter (1868-1920)

Comment: The corresponding noun is "(a)esthete", *a person who has or professes to have refined sensitivity toward the beauties of art or nature; a person who affects great love of art, music, poetry, etc., and indifference to practical matters*.

Answer (score 0):

***Optimist*** *&* ***Idealist*** are the closest that I can think of. Although, they aren't exclusive to just ***beauty.***